# Как интегрировать в Jquery Text Editor emodji

Tags: jquery

На сайте имеется стандартный [Jquery text editor](https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxeditor/jquery-editor-getting-started.htm?search=), который инициализируются данным способом:
`$(“.text-edit textarea”).jqte`.

Мне хотелось бы, что бы помимо стандартных функций можно бы вставлять смайлики/emodji.

Может есть уже готовые text editor с данным функционалом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так эмоджи - это просто текст. Вот, енотика добавил: ​​​

[image: Скриншот]

К сожалению, на SO сниппетом не работает, так что: https://jsfiddle.net/8e7j6n4o/

```js
var defaultTools = "bold italic underline | format font size | color background | left center right | outdent indent | ul ol | image | link | clean | html"

$('#editor').jqxEditor({
  tools: defaultTools + ' | racoon',
  createCommand: function(name) {
    switch (name) {
      case "racoon":
        return {
          type: 'button',
          tooltip: 'Racoon',
          init: function(widget) {
            widget.jqxButton({
              height: 25,
              width: 25
            });
            widget.html("<span style='line-height: 23px;'>&#129437;</span>");
          },
          refresh: function(widget, style) {
            // do something here when the selection is changed.
          },
          action: function(widget, editor) {
            return {
              command: 'inserthtml',
              value: "&#129437;"
            };
          }
        }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.energyblue.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/jqx-all.js"></script>

<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло!

Comment: Если вопрос еще не забыт, могли бы вы подсказать, как реализовать выпадающий список смайликов (аналогичный списку цветов) через это меню?